# Sci-fi film: peace ritual interrupted by a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, movie

There was a temple, or more likely a monastery of peace on a planet, and the ones who lived there where going to perform some kind of peace ritual - but they didn't manage to finish, because they where destroyed by spaceship above - it send part of it, kind of drill, which smashed into temple. I know it is not much, but that is all I remember. I appreciate your help - thanks in advance! ;)

Comment: You can do better: where you've seen it, when, how did they look like… I'm pretty sure you can remember **many** more details than these.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an episode in the miniseries capping the show Farscape. When the Scarrans destroyed the lost temple on Arnessk.

Comment: Can you provide more info?  Why does this remind you of the description?  Please provide a summary and/or a link to a summary.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about [Peacekeeper Wars: Part 1](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Peacekeeper_Wars:_Part_1), since the summary says "Jool sends a transmission from the planet, addressing the Scarran vessel, saying the inhabitants of Arnessk are peaceful ...  the Scarrans launch a missile which goes straight past Moya, and decimates the temple on the planet in a huge explosion."